# Disabling cancel-rating button in ratyrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you disable the cancel rating function in ratyrate? I have tried:

```
<%= rating_for @community, "friendliness", cancel: false %>
```

and checking the default value in `app/assets/javascripts/ratyrate.js.erb` to false. I have no knowledge in javascripting so I don't really have any clue on editing `app/assets/javascripts/JQuery.raty.js`

[This](http://www.sitepoint.com/ratyrate-add-rating-rails-app/) guide mentions disabling the method at the start but never really explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem does not look like supporting it. One of the work arounds is to disable it from css like this:

```
img.raty-cancel {
  display: none;
}
```

Since JS is not your option.

Another option is to disable it with javascript conditionally:

Assume that you don't want to show your rating in some conditions:

```
<% disable = "disable-cancel" if condition %>

<div class="<%= disable_cancel %>">
  <%= rating_for @community, "friendliness", cancel: false %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".disable-cancel img.raty-cancel").hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately that removes the whole rating.  Could you elaborate on the JS option, if it's not to much of an hassle?

Comment: No, it should not remove the whole rating because cancel rating button looks like this: <img title="Cancel current rating!" class="raty-cancel" src="/assets//cancel-off.png" alt="x">, so this style will only conceal the image.